How do I filter and retrieve only the latest related record in a Salesforce Analytics recipe?
I’m working with Salesforce Analytics (Tableau CRM) to create a recipe that pulls data from two related objects. One of the objects is a main record (e.g., Case), and the other stores related log entries in a lookup relationship.
Goal: I want to filter and retrieve only the latest log, per app and type (custom fields in log) for each case.
Current Approach:
I have set up a join in the recipe to bring in the log data, but I’m unsure how to filter down to only the most recent log entry per main record.
Questions:
What’s the best way to filter for the latest related record when using a lookup relationship in a recipe?
How can I use specific filters on related records to retrieve only the latest one for each main record?
Are there any alternative methods (e.g., Flow, Apex, custom fields) that would retrieve the logs I’m looking for more efficiently?

what do you mean by retrieving latest records? do you mean recently created or modified in some particular time frame?
